# Get Current IndexOf Children In List

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list of strings,when I remove one the indexof the strings do not change hence when I try removing another with the index higher than the current number I get and error saying the index in out of range.

```
 public class MyClass{

     public StackLayout SavedHoursLayout = new StackLayout {};
     public Label RemoveHoursLabel;
     public TapGestureRecognizer RemoveTapped;
     public Grid HoursRemoveGrid;
     public Button AddHoursButton = new Button();

     public MyClass()
     {
          Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children = { AddHoursButton,SavedHoursLayout }
            }
        AddHoursButton.Clicked+=AddHoursButton_Clicked;
         AddSavedHours();
     }
  public void AddSavedHours()
    {
        Label Time = new Label { };
        RemoveHoursLabel = new Label { Text="remove",TextColor=Color.Red,FontAttributes=FontAttributes.Italic};
        HoursRemoveGrid = new Grid();
        RemoveTapped = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        this.BindingContext = HoursRemoveGrid;

        HoursRemoveGrid.Children.Add(Time,0,0);
        HoursRemoveGrid.Children.Add(RemoveHoursLabel,1,0);
        SavedHoursLayout.Children.Add(HoursRemoveGrid);

        RemoveHoursLabel.GestureRecognizers.Add(RemoveTapped);
        RemoveTapped.Tapped += RemoveTapped_Tapped;


        void RemoveTapped_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int position = SavedHoursLayout.Children.IndexOf(HoursRemoveGrid);
            SavedHoursLayout.Children.RemoveAt(position);

        }
 }

    private void AddHoursButton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        AddSavedHours();
    }
  }
```

**Question**

after I add children to the `SavedHoursLayout`, and click on the `RemoveHoursLabel` it removes the current `RemoveHoursLabel` but the index of the rest remain the same hence when i click on another one it remove the child with the index assigned to it and if the index is out of bounds , I get an error saying

> index is out of range,should not be negative or above the number of items.

so how do I update the index of the children to the current one when a child is removed of the `SavedHoursLayout` changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the sender to obtain the current grid that you wish to remove:

```
void RemoveTapped_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var grid = (sender as Label).Parent as Grid;
    int position = SavedHoursLayout.Children.IndexOf(grid);
    SavedHoursLayout.Children.RemoveAt(position);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly,Thanks.